# Add variable to dockerfile{} section in Jenkinsfile to enable docker_buildkit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, docker-buildkit

This is snipshet of my code:

```
   stage('tf run') {
  agent {
    dockerfile {
      additionalBuildArgs "${ADDITIONAL_BUILD_ARGS}"
      registryCredentialsId "${REGISTRY_CREDENTIALS}"
      registryUrl "${REGISTRY_URL}"
      reuseNode true
    }
  }
```

Now I want do add special variable DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 when I run this peace of code.
For example in a shell it should look like: "DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build ."
I need it because I want to run my docker in docker_buildkit mode.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
environment {
    DOCKER_BUILDKIT='1'
}
```

Putting it in as an env variable in your pipeline will work

Comment: Where I should put this? inside pipeline or agent section?